# How to move elasticsearch nodes between two locations

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch setup, so that it stores the data at two locations meaning in elasticsearch.yml I have

path.data: /path_one/es_data,/path_two/elasticsearch

I was hoping elasticsearch would automatically figure out where more space is available and store new incoming data wherever possible, but instead, I found it starts to crash when short of memory at any one location. So I would like to move one node from path_one to path_two.

Currently, it looks like this

```
ls -lha /path_one/es_data/nodes/0/indices/
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 A4XXnhNdTwKILyeE39UosA
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 C2BPWKL4T3-jHIfZXNKG6g
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 c8mFFi56RAyRYNpHOUvG4g
drwxr-xr-x 6 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 DEk-qwdnSLOHbP_-nAhSdw
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 kV32aUcET1WrlKXWOunGhg
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 pGmjsSJHRAiMUC5paYfjag
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 T1k45bs2SUGHJ6dJniPjZg

ls -lha /path_two/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/
drwxr-xr-x 4 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 A4XXnhNdTwKILyeE39UosA
drwxr-xr-x 4 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 C2BPWKL4T3-jHIfZXNKG6g
drwxr-xr-x 4 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 c8mFFi56RAyRYNpHOUvG4g
drwxr-xr-x 5 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 DEk-qwdnSLOHbP_-nAhSdw
drwxr-xr-x 4 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 pGmjsSJHRAiMUC5paYfjag
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13
```

T1k45bs2SUGHJ6dJniPjZg
    drwxr-xr-x 4 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4.0K Mar  7 03:13 XpHUz15oTbGG0Bvnf2xZsw

So my first question is, why are some of the nodes present at both locations? And my second question is whether I can just

1. stop elasticsearch
2. copy nodes over
3. restart elasticsearch

or whether I have to do more?

EDIT: I found some messages in the logfiles which look related

```
[2019-03-07T17:08:21,910][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [WU6cQ-o] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [WU6cQ-oTR2Ssg3LzoI4_yg][WU6cQ-o][/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 984.7mb[1.6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-03-07T17:08:51,944][WARN ][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] [WU6cQ-o] [[paper-index/XpHUz15oTbGG0Bvnf2xZsw]] can not be imported as a dangling index, as index with same name already exists in cluster metadata
```

so it seems like elasticsearch is trying to move indices, but can't because there are already copies of these indices at the other location? Can I just delete the copies at the location where there is more space?

Comment: Hi @carl, have you checked my answer? has been of any use to you?

Answer (score 0):

An Elasticsearch instance [corresponds to one node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html). Setting two locations in `path.data` doesn't mean that you have two nodes running on the same host, but that you're storing the data of your node on two locations (see [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/path-settings.html)). Therefore, to **answer your first question**, it is to be expected that data of the same node is spread across locations.

As for **your second question**, I don't understand your process, mostly because I'm not sure that you're running multiple nodes.

From the [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/path-settings.html), all we know about data distribution across locations is that Elasticsearch stores the files related to the same shard in the same location.

Hope it helps